# Trouble creating a Feed in views

Tags: views, feeds

I am having trouble setting up an RSS feed page view. I created the page, and attached the proper path; when I go to the page I am prompted to download an XML file. Shouldn't I get a page that only shows the content for the feed? What am I missing here?

- I am using Firefox.
- I clicked a system generated RSS feed from a node, and got the feed page as I expected, so the output is not consistent.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Are we talking about an RSS feed? In that case it sounds like everything is working well, just your browser deciding to download the feed instead of displaying it. Does your browser render other feeds in the same format?

Comment: Are you creating a Page or a Feed? Be sure you choose Feed from the Add Display dropdown.